# Error in smart contract

Tags: solidity-0.8.x

[image: Image shows error that it is not able to estimate gas and this transaction may fail]// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract SupplyChain {
//Smart Contract owner will be the person who deploys the contract only he can authorize various roles like retailer, Manufacturer,etc
address public Owner;

```
//note this constructor will be called when smart contract will be deployed on blockchain
constructor() public {
    Owner = msg.sender;
}

//Roles (flow of pharma supply chain)
// RawMaterialSupplier; //This is where Manufacturer will get raw materials to make medicines
// Manufacturer;  //Various WHO guidelines should be followed by this person
// Distributor; //This guy distributes the medicines to retailers
// Retailer; //Normal customer buys from the retailer

//modifier to make sure only the owner is using the function
modifier onlyByOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == Owner);
    _;
}

//stages of a medicine in pharma supply chain
enum STAGE {
    Init,
    RawMaterialSupply,
    Manufacture,
    Distribution,
    Retail,
    sold
}
//using this we are going to track every single medicine the owner orders

//Medicine count
uint256 public medicineCtr = 0;
//Raw material supplier count
uint256 public rmsCtr = 0;
//Manufacturer count
uint256 public manCtr = 0;
//distributor count
uint256 public disCtr = 0;
//retailer count
uint256 public retCtr = 0;

//To store information about the medicine
struct medicine {
    uint256 id; //unique medicine id
    string name; //name of the medicine
    string description; //about medicine
    uint256 RMSid; //id of the Raw Material supplier for this particular medicine
    uint256 MANid; //id of the Manufacturer for this particular medicine
    uint256 DISid; //id of the distributor for this particular medicine
    uint256 RETid; //id of the retailer for this particular medicine
    STAGE stage; //current medicine stage
}

//To store all the medicines on the blockchain
mapping(uint256 => medicine) public MedicineStock;

//To show status to client applications
function showStage(uint256 _medicineID)
    public
    view
    returns (string memory)
{
    require(medicineCtr > 0);
    if (MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Init)
        return "Medicine Ordered";
    else if (MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.RawMaterialSupply)
        return "Raw Material Supply Stage";
    else if (MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Manufacture)
        return "Manufacturing Stage";
    else if (MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Distribution)
        return "Distribution Stage";
    else if (MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Retail)
        return "Retail Stage";
    else if (MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.sold)
        return "Medicine Sold";
}

//To store information about raw material supplier
struct rawMaterialSupplier {
    address addr;
    uint256 id; //supplier id
    string name; //Name of the raw material supplier
    string place; //Place the raw material supplier is based in
}

//To store all the raw material suppliers on the blockchain
mapping(uint256 => rawMaterialSupplier) public RMS;

//To store information about manufacturer
struct manufacturer {
    address addr;
    uint256 id; //manufacturer id
    string name; //Name of the manufacturer
    string place; //Place the manufacturer is based in
}

//To store all the manufacturers on the blockchain
mapping(uint256 => manufacturer) public MAN;

//To store information about distributor
struct distributor {
    address addr;
    uint256 id; //distributor id
    string name; //Name of the distributor
    string place; //Place the distributor is based in
}

//To store all the distributors on the blockchain
mapping(uint256 => distributor) public DIS;

//To store information about retailer
struct retailer {
    address addr;
    uint256 id; //retailer id
    string name; //Name of the retailer
    string place; //Place the retailer is based in
}

//To store all the retailers on the blockchain
mapping(uint256 => retailer) public RET;

//To add raw material suppliers. Only contract owner can add a new raw material supplier
function addRMS(
    address _address,
    string memory _name,
    string memory _place
) public onlyByOwner() {
    rmsCtr++;
    RMS[rmsCtr] = rawMaterialSupplier(_address, rmsCtr, _name, _place);
}

//To add manufacturer. Only contract owner can add a new manufacturer
function addManufacturer(
    address _address,
    string memory _name,
    string memory _place
) public onlyByOwner() {
    manCtr++;
    MAN[manCtr] = manufacturer(_address, manCtr, _name, _place);
}

//To add distributor. Only contract owner can add a new distributor
function addDistributor(
    address _address,
    string memory _name,
    string memory _place
) public onlyByOwner() {
    disCtr++;
    DIS[disCtr] = distributor(_address, disCtr, _name, _place);
}

//To add retailer. Only contract owner can add a new retailer
function addRetailer(
    address _address,
    string memory _name,
    string memory _place
) public onlyByOwner() {
    retCtr++;
    RET[retCtr] = retailer(_address, retCtr, _name, _place);
}

//To supply raw materials from RMS supplier to the manufacturer
function RMSsupply(uint256 _medicineID) public {
    require(_medicineID > 0 && _medicineID <= medicineCtr);
    uint256 _id = findRMS(msg.sender);
    require(_id > 0);
    require(MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Init);
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].RMSid = _id;
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage = STAGE.RawMaterialSupply;
}

//To check if RMS is available in the blockchain
function findRMS(address _address) private view returns (uint256) {
    require(rmsCtr > 0);
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= rmsCtr; i++) {
        if (RMS[i].addr == _address) return RMS[i].id;
    }
    return 0;
}

//To manufacture medicine
function Manufacturing(uint256 _medicineID) public {
    require(_medicineID > 0 && _medicineID <= medicineCtr);
    uint256 _id = findMAN(msg.sender);
    require(_id > 0);
    require(MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.RawMaterialSupply);
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].MANid = _id;
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage = STAGE.Manufacture;
}

//To check if Manufacturer is available in the blockchain
function findMAN(address _address) private view returns (uint256) {
    require(manCtr > 0);
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= manCtr; i++) {
        if (MAN[i].addr == _address) return MAN[i].id;
    }
    return 0;
}

//To supply medicines from Manufacturer to distributor
function Distribute(uint256 _medicineID) public {
    require(_medicineID > 0 && _medicineID <= medicineCtr);
    uint256 _id = findDIS(msg.sender);
    require(_id > 0);
    require(MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Manufacture);
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].DISid = _id;
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage = STAGE.Distribution;
}

//To check if distributor is available in the blockchain
function findDIS(address _address) private view returns (uint256) {
    require(disCtr > 0);
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= disCtr; i++) {
        if (DIS[i].addr == _address) return DIS[i].id;
    }
    return 0;
}

//To supply medicines from distributor to retailer
function Retail(uint256 _medicineID) public {
    require(_medicineID > 0 && _medicineID <= medicineCtr);
    uint256 _id = findRET(msg.sender);
    require(_id > 0);
    require(MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Distribution);
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].RETid = _id;
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage = STAGE.Retail;
}

//To check if retailer is available in the blockchain
function findRET(address _address) private view returns (uint256) {
    require(retCtr > 0);
    for (uint256 i = 1; i <= retCtr; i++) {
        if (RET[i].addr == _address) return RET[i].id;
    }
    return 0;
}

//To sell medicines from retailer to consumer
function sold(uint256 _medicineID) public {
    require(_medicineID > 0 && _medicineID <= medicineCtr);
    uint256 _id = findRET(msg.sender);
    require(_id > 0);
    require(_id == MedicineStock[_medicineID].RETid); //Only correct retailer can mark medicine as sold
    require(MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage == STAGE.Retail);
    MedicineStock[_medicineID].stage = STAGE.sold;
}

// To add new medicines to the stock
function addMedicine(string memory _name, string memory _description)
    public
    onlyByOwner()
{
    require((rmsCtr > 0) && (manCtr > 0) && (disCtr > 0) && (retCtr > 0));
    medicineCtr++;
    MedicineStock[medicineCtr] = medicine(
        medicineCtr,
        _name,
        _description,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        STAGE.Init
    );
}
```

}
I have this smart contract when I compiled it, it showed me following error.
project source: https://github.com/Faizack/Supply-Chain-Blockchain